# Infer user (mail address) from the pid of imapd process

Tags: imap, courier

on my server is installed Courier Mail Server. It happens that one imapd process uses tons of the system resources blocking the entire server.
I would like to track down the user (i.e. the mail address in Courier Mail) that is running that process. Please note: not the linux user, but the mail address.
Is it possibile to infer the email address of a process given the PID of a imapd command process?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In my installation I solved with `top -c`

One example output is, on the command column:

```
/usr/bin/imapd /usr/home/user/vmail/domain/**mail_address**/mail/
```